# Loadrunner monitoring of VMWare ESX host

Tags: monitoring, vmware, loadrunner, sitescope

Looking into setting up a Loadrunner monitor for a ESX host running my test virtual machines. Some quick searching is not finding any native ESX monitors. Can i use some Linux kind of thing? I have seen some doco which suggests Sitescope does this. Thoughts?

Comment: Use the SNMP monitor with SNMP agent on the ESX host

Comment: Alternative path.  Use an RTE virtual user to sign into the command line interface of the ESX host, run your queries manually, correlate for the information and use the datapoint API to create your stats